# Scraping links from a page using Beautiful Soup, how can I now iterate through these links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here's my code for retrieving the links on a page.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re

def getExternalLinks(includeURL):
    html = urlopen(includeURL)
    bsObj = soup(html, "html.parser")
    externalLinks = []
    links = bsObj.findAll("a", 
    href=re.compile("^(http://www.homedepot.com/b)"))
    for link in links:
        if link.attrs['href'] is not None:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in externalLinks:
                externalLinks.append(link.attrs['href'])

    print(externalLinks)

getExternalLinks("http://www.homedepot.com/")
```

The links are stored in the array below.

```
['http://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances/N-5yc1vZbv1w?cm_sp=d-flyout-Appliances', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Bath/N-5yc1vZbzb3?cm_sp=d-flyout-Bath_and_Faucets', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Decor/N-5yc1vZas6p?cm_sp=d-flyout-Blinds_and_Decor', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials/N-5yc1vZaqns?cm_sp=d-flyout-Building_Materials', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Doors-Windows/N-5yc1vZaqih?cm_sp=d-flyout-Doors_and_Windows', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical/N-5yc1vZarcd?cm_sp=d-flyout-Electrical', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Flooring/N-5yc1vZaq7r?cm_sp=d-flyout-Flooring_and_Area_Rugs', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Hardware/N-5yc1vZc21m', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Heating-Venting-Cooling/N-5yc1vZc4k8?cm_sp=d-flyout-Heating_and_Cooling', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Kitchen/N-5yc1vZar4i?cm_sp=d-flyout-Kitchen', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Garden-Center/N-5yc1vZbx6k?cm_sp=d-flyout-Lawn_and_Garden', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Lighting-Ceiling-Fans/N-5yc1vZbvn5?cm_sp=d-flyout-Lighting_and_Ceiling_Fans', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors/N-5yc1vZbx82?cm_sp=d-flyout-Outdoor_Living', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Paint/N-5yc1vZar2d?cm_sp=d-flyout-Paint', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing/N-5yc1vZbqew?cm_sp=d-flyout-Plumbing', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Storage-Organization/N-5yc1vZas7e?cm_sp=d-flyout-Storage_and_Organization', 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools/N-5yc1vZc1xy']
```

Now I am trying to iterate through these links and go to each page and get information. I am getting some errors that continue popping up when I run the next code.

```
def getInternalLinks(includeLinks):
    internalHTML = urlopen(includeLinks)
    Inner_bsObj = soup(internalHTML, "html.parser")
    internalLinks = []
    inner_links = Inner_bsObj.findAll("a", "href")

    for inner_link in inner_links:
        if inner_link.attrs['href'] is not None:
            if inner_link.attrs['href'] not in internalLinks:
                internalLinks.append(inner_link.attrs['href'])
    print(internalLinks)

getInternalLinks(getExternalLinks("http://www.homedepot.com"))




File "C:/Users/anag/Documents/Python 
Scripts/Webscrapers/BeautifulSoup/HomeDepot/HomeDepotScraper.py", line 20, 
in getInternalLinks
internalHTML = urlopen(includeLinks)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

How should I go about extracting information from each of the webpages that I stored in the externalLinks array?

Comment: What information do you want from one of those pages?

Comment: There are additional urls from those pages that I want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a list and not an array.  Array in Python means Numpy arrays most of the time which are quite different from lists.

The problem with your code is that the `getExternalLinks()` function returns `None` and you give that as argument to the `getInternalLinks()` function which expects a single URL.  The first function needs to return the list (or set) of URLs instead of (just) printing them, and then you need a loop over the return value and feed each URL to the second function.

Both functions contain almost the same code.  Sans the name differences it is just the parameter(s) of the `findAll()` method that differ.  I would refactor this into a common function.

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_links(url, attrs=None):
    if attrs is None:
        attrs = dict()
    links = set()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
    for a_node in soup.find_all('a', attrs):
        link = a_node.get('href')
        if link is not None:
            links.add(link)
    return links


def main():
    external_links = get_links(
        'http://www.homedepot.com/',
        {'href': re.compile('^(http://www.homedepot.com/b)')},
    )
    print(external_links)
    for link in external_links:
        # 
        # TODO I am not sure if you really want to filter on <a> elements
        #      with a class of 'href' but that is what your code did, so...
        # 
        internal_links = get_links(link, {'class': 'href'})
        print(internal_links)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```